# Why is the interpretation of infinite union of sets as a limit so incorrect (or even dangerous)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In some reputable [notes on a Probability course at the IIT](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/%7Ekrishnaj/ee5110notes.htm) I read:

> When the index set $\mathcal I$ is a finite set, say $\mathcal I = {1, 2, 3}$ the definition of union given above coincides with the “middle-school” understanding of unions, i.e., taking the union of sets one-at-a-time. For example, $\bigcup_{i=1}^3 A_i= A_1 \bigcup A_2 \bigcup A_3.$ However, this “one-by-one” interpretation completely breaks down when the index set $\mathcal I$ is infinite. For example when $\mathcal I = \mathbb N,$ the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ does not have any interpretation in terms of taking unions one by one, till infinity. After all, there is no $A_∞$ in the family $\{A_i, i ∈ \mathbb N\},$ and **there is no notion of “limiting unions”.** Thus, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ should be interpreted just as Definition 1.3 says: it is the set of all elements contained in at least one of the $A_i, i ∈ \mathbb N.$ In order to avoid the (dangerous) temptation to interpret $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ as **some sort of a limit of finite, “one-by-one” unions**, a better notation would be to use $\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N} A_i,$ instead of the potentially misleading but more commonly used notation $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i.$

What sort of misunderstanding would the approach of this union as a limit result in?

Comment: If the sets $A_i$ aren't nested, one might mistakenly believe that some element isn't in the union because it's only in finitely many $A_i$.

Comment: Reputable or not, it's still possible to be wrongheaded.  Notice that $x \in \cup_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_{i}$ if and only if $x \in \cup_{i = 1}^{N} A_{i}$ for all but finitely many $N$ --- that already makes me wonder why the quote is as adamant about the union *not* being a limit of finite unions as it is.  There is a notion of a limit of sequence of sets, which includes countably infinite unions.  It's ironic because it seems to see most application in measure theory, especially probability theory.  (See Borel-Cantelli Lemma.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: Along with Peter's comment above, I observe that $$\cup_{i=1}^n A_i \nearrow \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$$ which is used all the time in probability to conclude (from "continuity of probability") that $P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[\cup_{i=1}^n A_i]$.  Countable unions can always be viewed as limits of finite unions. So perhaps the spirit of the IIT notes would be better served by an example of a union over an **uncountably infinite index set** $V$, such as $\cup_{v \in V} A_v$.

Comment: It’s certainly very dangerous to think that a colimit is a limit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason viewing infinite unions as limits is **technically incorrect in this context** is for the exact reason your quoted passage says: there is no definition of a "limit" when it comes to taking the union of sets **in this context**. When you think of, for example
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)
$$
this has a definition. ${\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists\ \delta>0}$... yadda yadda yadda.

But when it comes to sets, <strike>we don't have any such notion. Nor do we need it.</strike> You can simply say that ${x \in \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}A_i}$ if and only if ${x \in A_i}$ for some ${i \in \mathbb{N}}$. That's it. That's all we need to define the infinite union.

**EDIT**: @Peter Morfe has corrected me in the comments of this post. There is such a notion defined, and it is useful in a lot of contexts. The main point still stands, though, that we do not *need* a notion of set limits to define at least a basic notion of the union and intersection of sets. In fact, for the union/intersection of uncountably infinitely many sets, the standard definition I referenced is the one you need to use.

Comment: (Countably) infinite unions *are* limits.  There is a notion of limsup, liminf, and limit of sets; and countably infinite unions are among the simplest examples.  The OP's quote seems to be aimed at undergraduates (interpreting it very charitably).  In measure theory and particularly probability, limits of sets are actually pretty important (and eventually become intuitive). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: @PeterMorfe The quote can be found I, the first lecture of the course, within a PDF linked now in the OP.

Comment: @PeterMorfe thank you for correcting me, I have edited my answer and attributed you in the edit

Answer (score 0):

You're really looking for $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of sets. Let $(A_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a countable family of sets. Then $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad \liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n\geq 0} \bigcap_{k \geq n}A_k.$$If these two sets coincide, then we can write $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n$.

**Example:** if $A_n=[-n,n]$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}[-n,n]=\Bbb R$, as you would expect.

In general, if $(A_n)_{n\geq 0}$ in non-increasing or non-decreasing, the limit exists and it equals their union or intersection.

The bottom line is that in the same way that the limit of a numerical real sequence exists if and only if both the limsup and liminf exist and are equal, this is what you have to be careful with when dealing with sets.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that $\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \cup_{n = 1}^{N} A_{n}$, almost contradicting the OP's quote.  That quote may be useful for teaching undergraduates, but it isn't an accurate statement from where I sit.

Comment: If I may, two follow-up questions, likely stupid, but here it goes: One, in $\limsup_{n\to \infty}A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k $ wouldn't the $\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k $ part just include everything, leaving the intersection part redundant? And two, in $[-n,n]$ is $n$ a real number?

Comment: 1) No, because you don't know whether the sequence is monotone or not (try any example and you will see); 2) Obviously a natural number.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the sequence part, and it may be beyond the scope of this interaction, but wouldn't the union be dominated by the biggest set in the sequence, regardless of the order? All its elements would remain included in said union from that point on.

Comment: Again: the sequence is not necessarily monotone. There might be no "biggest set" in the sequence.