# What is the mechanics of the union-intersection along a sequence of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

This question came about after I got stuck trying to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4069761/878105).

When $n\to \infty$ I don't understand why in a countable family of sets $(A_n)_{n\geq 0}$ the operation

$$\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k $$

depends on whether the sequence is monotonous or not.

It is likely that I don't understand the symbols, or that I am just too dumb. Let's see... Should I read this as a composition of operations? If so, when I start from the inside, i.e.

$$\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$$

I necessarily end up with all the elements in all the sets combined into a single set. At that point this entire set containing all possible elements in any one of the sets $A_k$ is intersect-ioned with all of the sets $A_k,$ looking for elements that are in all sets. Is that it? If this is correct, then why does the order of the monotony of the sequence matter? Can I get an example?

---

Post-mortem:

'
For a finite collection of sets:

$$
\begin{align}
A_0&=\{a,b\}\\
A_1&=\{a,x\}\\
A_3&=\{a,x,y\}\\
A_4&=\{a,c,d,y\}\\[3ex]
\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k &=\{a,b,x,y,c,d\}\cap\{a,x,y,c,d\}\cap\{a,x,y,c,d\}\\
&=\{a,x,y,c,d\}\\[3ex]
\bigcup_{n\geq 0} \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k
&=\{a\}\cup\{a\}\cup\{a,y\}=\{a,y\}
\end{align}
$$

In pseudo-code $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k $:

`for`  $n$ `in` $n=0$ `to` $\infty:$

`for`  $k$ `in` $n$ `to` $\infty:$

$B_k \leftarrow A_k \cup A_{k+1} \cup A_{k+2} \cdots$

$B_0 \cap B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \cdots$

The pictorial intuition is that for an element $\color{blue}\spadesuit$ to be in $\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k $ it would have to keep on appearing so that no matter how far we go into infinity it appears in *some subset* to as to be part of all $B_k$'s, and hence, in the intersection:

$$\{\cdots\},\cdots,\{\cdots\},\{\cdots\},\{\cdots,\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\{\cdots\},\{\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\cdots,\{\cdots\},\{\cdots,\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\cdots$$

On the other hand, $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k $ is more demanding, requiring that $\color{blue}\spadesuit$ appears consistently after a certain point:

$$\{\cdots\},\cdots,\{\cdots\},\{\cdots\},\{\cdots,\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\{\cdots,\color{blue}\spadesuit\},\{\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\cdots,\{\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\{\cdots,\color{blue}\spadesuit,\cdots\},\cdots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest a way of thinking about

$$\bigcap_{n\ge 0}\bigcup_{k\ge n} A_k$$

and

$$\bigcup_{n\ge 0}\bigcap_{k\ge n} A_k$$

that may be helpful.

How does something get into either of these sets?

- $x\in\bigcap\limits_{n\ge 0}\bigcup\limits_{k\ge n} A_k$ if and only if $x\in\bigcup\limits_{k\ge n}A_k$ for each $n\ge 0$, which is the case if and only if for each $n\ge 0$ there is a $k\ge n$ such that $x\in A_k$. And this is the same as saying that $x$ is in infinitely many of the sets $A_k$: no matter how far out in the sequence of sets you go, there is one further out that contains $x$.
- $x\in\bigcup\limits_{n\ge 0}\bigcap\limits_{k\ge n}A_k$ if and only if there is an $n\ge 0$ such that $x\in\bigcap\limits_{k\ge n}A_k$, which is the case if and only if there is an $n\ge 0$ such that $x\in A_k$ for **every** $k\ge n$. This just says that $x$ is in every $A_k$ from some point on: it is in all but finitely many of the sets $A_k$.

To sum up:

- $x\in\bigcap\limits_{n\ge 0}\bigcup\limits_{k\ge n} A_k$ if and only if $x$ belongs to infinitely many of the sets $A_k$, and
- $x\in\bigcup\limits_{n\ge 0}\bigcap\limits_{k\ge n} A_k$ if and only if $x$ is in all but finitely many of the sets $A_k$ or, equivalently, $x$ is in every $A_k$ from some point on.

Comment: Thank you very much! Clear, non-patronizing or dismissive exposition. Much appreciated in all its rarity.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Read it from left to right, like a double summation.  First, we choose $n$.  Then $\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k$ is the set $B_n$, say, of all elements that are in one of the $A_k$ with index $\geq n$.
$$B_n = A_n\cup A_{n+1}\cup A_{n+2}\cup\cdots$$
and $\bigcap_{n\geq0}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k$ is the set of elements in all of the $B_n$
$$\bigcap_{n\geq0}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k = B_0\cap B_1\cap B_2\cap\cdots$$
The intersection is not redundant.  Consider an element $x$ that is in $A_0$ but none of the other $A_n$.  Then $x\in B_0, x\notin B_1,\ x\notin B_2, \dots$ so $x\notin C:=\bigcap_{n\geq0}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k$

In fact, C is precisely the set of elements in infinitely many of the $A_n$.  (If $x$ is in only finitely many of the $A_n$ then there is some $n$ such that $n\geq N\implies x\notin A_n$.  Consequently, $x\notin B_N$.)

You might want to convince yourself that if we interchange the union and intersection, then $$\bigcup_{n\geq0}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k$$
is the set of all elements is all but finitely many of the $A_n$

Comment: If you kindly check the comments in the answer to another question I posted ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4069761/878105)) it is likely that you will see why I am struggling with that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @N I'll try to be more explicit in my answer.  Give me just a few minutes.

Comment: Do you ,mean "right to left" at the beginning?

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate No, I mean left to right.  It is the intersection over all $n\geq 0$ of the intersection ... If you try to read it right to left, it doesn't make sense.  What does $k\geq n$ mean?  $n$ hasn't even been mentioned.

Comment: Very enlightening your last comment! Yet it seems like following your answer, you first pick $n,$ but immediately after we leave the $\bigcap$ to the side, and focus first on the right-most operation in the expression, i.e. the $\bigcup,$ only to later (in your second paragraph) go back to left-most operation in the expression (intersection). A bit bouncy! Just making sure I follow...

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate I suggested you read it from left to right to understand what it means, but then you evaluate it from left to right, at least partly.  Just like we read $\sin x^2$ as "the sine of $x$ squared," but we evaluate $x^2$ before sine.

Comment: I wish I could have accepted two answers, and I had to settle for upvoting yours, and going for the one answer that was most useful at the time I read it based on my specific difficulties understanding. I wonder if you'd care to correct some LaTeX issue in your answer (also, I think $C$ is not clearly defined).

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

They are answering the specific question "wouldn't the $\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$ part just include everything, leaving the intersection part redundant?" The answer is no, only if the $A_k$ are monotone increasing to $\mathbb{R}$.

Your interpretation of $\bigcap_{n \geq 0} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$ is exactly correct. The comments in the other post are just pointing out that $\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{R}$ (although it is in their example, which is perhaps why the comments are confusing).

Comment: The following is strictly intended to follow your answer: Who is 'they'? I am not sure if it is the  person who answered the prior question, it is you, or it is the terminology. Could you frame a bit the answer so that it is more self-contained. Thank you!

Comment: "They" is the person who says it matters whether the sequence is monotone or not - Ivo Terek. The "it" in "it matters" does not refer to the value of $\limsup A_n$ or $\liminf A_n$, but rather the claim "$\bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$ contains everything."

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that part. I see that they bring up a close interval $[-n,n]$ which tends to $\mathbb R$ as $n\to \infty,$ but I thought we were talking about any sets with $A_k,$ in which case I don't see in the second paragraph of your answer how $\mathbb R$ comes about.

Comment: Ivo Terek is talking about any sets $A_k$, while giving a particular example. Your comments are about the particular example. The only reason I bring up $\mathbb{R}$ is because of the claim "$\bigcup_{k \geq n } A_k$ contains everything" (i.e., equals $\mathbb{R}$). That is true in the particular example Ivo gives, but of course it will not be true in general.